# "2048" game in JavaFX

Tags: java, beginner, game, javafx, 2048

I wrote my first code in Java and I need  constructive criticism and code review.

This is an implementation of the well-known "2048" sliding-blocks game.

```
package com.example.simple2048game;

import static javafx.scene.text.Font.font;

public class GameBoard {
     static double PANE_SIZE = 100 * GameMatrix.getInstance().getMatrixSize();
      static final double RECTANGLE_SIZE = PANE_SIZE / GameMatrix.getInstance().getMatrixSize();

    public enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }
    public static final class GameMatrix {


        private final int matrixSize = 4;
        private int[][] gameMatrix;
        private static volatile GameMatrix INSTANCE;

        public int getMatrixSize() {
            return matrixSize;
        }

        public int[][] getGameMatrix() {
            return gameMatrix;
        }

        public void setGameMatrix(int[][] newMatrix) {
            this.gameMatrix = newMatrix;
        }
        private GameMatrix() {
            gameMatrix = new int[matrixSize][matrixSize];

        }
        public static GameMatrix getInstance() {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized (GameMatrix.class) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE = new GameMatrix();
                    }
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
        record Point(int x, int y) {
            Point(int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Latest version is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Hathor875/Simple-JavaFX-2048-GAME).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Obviously the code is for a game of 2048, however it would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ 
Basically, I'm mainly concerned about the cleanliness of the code and not about the game's algorithms themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough here to meaningfully review.  Most of the code seems to be missing from the question.  Remember that here on Code Review, we have quite generous limit on question size (~64k characters).

Answer (score 4):

`GameMatrix` isn't easily constructible, as it enforces a singleton pattern.  In my view, that's an antipattern, as it makes it impossible to run unit-tests in parallel.

In this code, I'd consider the singleton to be an *anti*-pattern, which is equivalent to (and inferior to) a simple global variable.

Even worse, the `setGameMatrix` allows callers to replace `gameMatrix` with a value that doesn't match `matrixSize`, potentially leading to erroneous operation (such as raising exceptions).  If we believe we really need `setGameMatrix()`, it needs to be a lot more defensive about its arguments.